# Change the digital cert provider for Silverlight OOB app and updater will still work?

Tags: c#, silverlight, ssl, silverlight-5.0, digital-certificate

I have several legacy Silverlight OOB applications that are digitally signed with code signing certs.  My company wants to change certificate providers so basically try to create identical certs with a different provider.  Will the Silverlight updater update a Silverlight OOB application signed with a certificate, with identical company information, from a different provider?  Specifically they want to move from Thawte to Digicert.

Comment: Hi Steve,  Did you ever find a solution to this problem?

Comment: I had to get special approval to go back to Thawte and get an cert with the old sha1 algorithm.  Moving to a new more up to day algorithm was changing the CN name and that is what was causing Silverlight to throw a security exception.  This application is considered legacy and will be replaced with an html5 solution in the future so it is ok.  I am afraid at some point, certificate authorities will refuse to issue sha1 certs so could potentially be in a bad situation some day if this code lives on for too long.